# it'll give me a parser error

Tags: solidity, error

[image]

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0; 

contract fisrtCoin {

    address deployer; 
    mapping(address=>uint) balances;  

    public function fisrtcoin() {
        deployer = msg.sender;  
    }



    public function giveCoin(uint amount, address receiver) {
      if(msg.sender == deployer){
          balances[receiver] += amount;
      }
      else {
          throw; 
      }
    }

    public function viewBalance() returns (uint) {
        return balances[msg.sender];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First: the modifier come after the function, so it will be

```
function fisrtcoin() public  {
    deployer = msg.sender;  
}
```

Second user constructor key word, so it will be

```
constructor() external {
    deployer = msg.sender;  
}
```

Third  **throw**; is deprecated and you dont need an "if else"
you can use require(condition, "revert message") instead

```
require(msg.sender == deployer, "error sender is not deployer");
balances[receiver] += amount;
```

Forth when your function only ask for data and dont change it, then you need to add the **view** modifier

```
function viewBalance() public view returns (uint) {
    return balances[msg.sender];
}
```

see this https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/contracts.html#functions and try to finde up to date examples :) truffle and truffle boxes are a great place to start

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `public` statement after the declaration of parameters, remember that since version 0.5.0 `constructor` is better suited in this case.

Also `throw` is deprecated in version 0.5.0, in that case, is better to use `revert()`, `require` or `assert` depending on your logic.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

    contract firstCoin{

address deployer; 
mapping(address=>uint) balances;  

constructor() public {
    deployer = msg.sender;  
}



function giveCoin(uint amount,address receiver) public
{
  if(msg.sender == deployer){

    balances[receiver] += amount;

  }
  else{
    revert(); 
  }
}

function viewBalance() public view returns (uint)
{
  return balances[msg.sender];
}
}
```